# how to make Drop Down Lists in gsp from BootStrap.groovy

Tags: grails

I want to make a drop down using the data given in the BootStrap.groovy.

My City domain class

```
package city.model

   class City  {

        String cityName

        static constraints = {

                cityName(maxSize: 50) }
    }
```

In my Service class

```
public class CityService {

def citySelect(String cityName) //this is just a sample
{
City city = new City()
city.cityName = city.findByCityName(cityName)
}
}
```

controller

```
public class CityController {
def cityService
def 
def selCity() {
def selectCity =  cityService.citySelect(params.cityName){
if(selectCity != null){
render view // my view
}
else{
render view // error select again view
  }
 }
}
```

BootStrap.groovy

```
import city.City;
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        for(String cityName in ['Addis Ababa', 'Semera','Asosa','Gondar', 'Jijiga','Harar', 'Dire Dawa', 'Bahir Dar',
            'Hawassa', 'Arba Minch', 'Adama', 'Mekelle']) {

            City.findOrSaveByCityName(cityName).save()
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

i used this

```
<g:select name="cities" from="${City.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="cityName"/>
 in my view but showing error    cannot envoke method list on null object
```

What is wrong within mu code and what should i do to make it work. please any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have misunderstood the point of Bootstrap.

Bootstrap as per the naming convention is the part that is triggered when your site is booting up.

You would typically use it to ensure required db table records are generated before it has booted up i.e. admin account or in your case generation of some cities.

You would not be using Bootstrap to interact with the records you generated in the way of editing or selecting.

Once this has all be done and saved - you would have also used the Controllers/Views to list/view/update/add cities.

You would create your g:select tags in these views and matching controllers that would query the records you have saved via bootstrap

**E2A:**

Ok Just read your comment

Either use an import on the top of your gsp

```
<%@ page import="city.City" %>
```

or  call full packaged path to City domainClass **city.City.list**

```
<g:select name="cities" from="${city.City.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="cityName"/>
```

Comment: i did use Service and controllers. then when i try to to use the <g:select name="cities" from="${City.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="cityName"/>    Error showing when i try to access the page .... i updated my question to lshow how i used the service and controller

Answer (score 1):

```
<g:select name="city" from="${city.model.City.list()}" optionValue="${cityName}" 
      noSelection="['':'-Please select the City-']" optionKey="id"/>
```

this could work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<g:select name="cities" from="${city.model.City.list()}" 
    optionKey="id" optionValue="cityName"/>
```

However, executing queries like `city.model.City.list()` in a GSP is not a recommended practice. Instead you should retrieve your data (the list of cities) in a controller action or a service and pass that via the model to the GSP.

Comment: City.list() its related to what I posted in my answer - full package path to get to city you can also use city?.City?.list() - the question marks will ensure no result rather than an error response so a blank selection

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of the Cities you inserted into the Database in the Bootstrap.groovy (in a view i.e [viewName].gsp)

Mark up is like so

```
<g:select name="city" from="${city.model.City.list()}" value="${city.name}" 
      noSelection="['':'-Please select the City-']" optionKey="id"/>
```

However, the Bootstrap should be for initialization of Database and Application defaults, Also to perform start (Startup in the init closure while shutdown in the destroy Closure).